# android AOSP Cross Compilers confusion

Tags: android, android-source

I am new to this AOSP building, and I have few questions.

There is a folder named 'prebuilds' which it seems has cross compiled binaries of compiler related tools. But there are more

**Can someone explain how the below compilers differ from each other,**

```
./gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.6/bin/arm-eabi-gcc
./gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
./gcc/linux-x86/host/x86_64-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/bin/x86_64-linux-gcc
./gcc/linux-x86/host/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/bin/i686-linux-gcc
```

My tiny knowledge about this: Correct me if i'm wrong?

```
 i686-linux-gcc    -> compiler that compiles for x86 - 32 bit target.
 86_64-linux-gcc   -> compiler that compiles for x86 - 64 bit target.
 arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  -> ?
 arm-eabi-gcc               ->  ?
```

Thanks for your help!!.

Answer (score 0):

yes, arm-eabi-gcc and arm-linux-androideabi-gcc toolchains which come with Android NDK are bit different, you can refer about arm-linux-androideabi-gcc in git or in file docs/CHANGES.html in your local NDK install.

Comment: do you know what toolchain should be used to compile for aosp?